# Querying third party json api using request-promise

Tags: json, node.js, express, mean-stack, request-promise

I've been trying to get this to work all day but I can't figure out what the issue is. I'm trying to query a third party api using request promise but I keep getting all the json objects back instead of just the ones for day 1. My goal is to take two dates that are entered by the user and then display the average temperature for each day for that time period. 
Is there a better way to do this or am I just not understanding how to solve this problem?

```
router.get('/weather/averageTemps/:day', function () {

const options = {
    url: 'http://5a3844bcbe179d0012970288.mockapi.io/api/v1/weather',
    method: 'GET',
    qs: {
        "day": 1
    },
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
    }
};

console.log(options.qs);


var req = request(options, function (err, res, body) {
    var json = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(json);
   });

});
```

Sample Json

```
 {
    "averageTemp": 1,
    "chanceOfPrecip": "0.4782",
    "skyCondition": "cloudy",
    "month": 0,
    "day": 0
},
{
    "averageTemp": 8,
    "chanceOfPrecip": "0.0178",
    "skyCondition": "mostly sunny",
    "month": 0,
    "day": 1
},
{
    "averageTemp": 7,
    "chanceOfPrecip": "0.9158",
    "skyCondition": "mostly cloudy",
    "month": 0,
    "day": 2
},
```

GET /api/weather/averageTemps/something?day=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: cd9b90cd-136b-0f47-981d-8f4862b8ff26

Comment: What do you want the query string to look like in the external request url?  Right now you have `?q=1`.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: Ultimately it needs to be something like ?start date & end date using a start day and month and an end day and month. This is my first time trying query strings so I'm not too sure what the best way to do this is. The code above was my attempt at trying to get something simple working.

Comment: Well, the `qs` object you pass to `request()` is key/value pairs that will be put in the query string.  What your code shows now is `?q=xxx`.  I suspect you're getting lots of data back because your query string is wrong.  That's why I was asking you for specifics about what the query string is supposed to be (which you still haven't shown).

Comment: From what I understand the url needs to be 
localhost:3000/api/weather/averageTemps/?day=1

Now if I use localhost:3000/api/weather/averageTemps with the above code I get all the results
I can also use localhost:3000/api/weather/averageTemps?day=1 and get all the results

Now if I change averageTemps/:day
I can use localhost:3000/api/weather/averageTemps/?day=1 and that will return the entire data set as well. 
I've tinkered around with it for a while now and I can't get it to return anything other than the entire data set.

Comment: Well, there's no much we can do if you don't know what URL will work for you.

Comment: Alright....
The url for the third party database is 'http://5a3844bcbe179d0012970288.mockapi.io/api/v1/weather'

The route I want to use in my application is
/weather/averageTemps

How do I query that database from my application.

Comment: I'm not sure how you think we would know this?  If you're trying to use some service on the internet, you need to find the documentation for how its API works.